# Format RSA Key to Public Key with OpenSSL in C++

Tags: c++, openssl

I have an RSA key of 538 hexadecimal characters like this:

```
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
```

1. The first problem I have is that I need my key of 538 characters to get its public key (which according to an online program returns a 588-character key) but I can not find how to convert it. I am currently using that online program to get the public key.
2. The second problem is when I already have the public Rsa key of 588 characters, i need to move to this format:

   -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- 
   MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQCgF35rHhOWi9+r4n9xM/ejvMEs 
   Q8h6lams962k4U0WSdfySUevhyI1bd3FRIb5fFqSBt6qPTiiiIw0KXte5dANB6lP 
   e6HdUPTA/U4xHWi2FB/BfAyPsOlUBfFp6dtkEEcEKt+Z8KTJYJEerRie24y+nsfZ 
   MnLBst6tsEBfx/U75wIBAw==
   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Currently I do it "by hand" converting my RSA key from 588 characters to base64 and pasting the values ​​one by one in this way:

```
unsigned char* publicKey;

string base64_encode(unsigned char const* bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len) 
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    unsigned char char_array_3[3];
    unsigned char char_array_4[4];
    string ret;

    while (in_len--) 
    {
        char_array_3[i++] = *(bytes_to_encode++);

        if (i == 3) 
        {
            char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
            char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
            char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
            char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

            for(i = 0; (i < 4) ; i++)
            {
                ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
            }

            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (i)
    {
        for(j = i; j < 3; j++)
        {
            char_array_3[j] = '\0';
        }

        char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
        char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
        char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
        char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

        for (j = 0; (j < i + 1); j++)
        {
            ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[j]];
        }

        while((i++ < 3))
        {
            ret += '=';
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

bool format_to_Public_Key()
{
    string Rsa_588 = "3082010902820....10203010001"; //588 Length RSA key

    if(Rsa_588.length() == 588)
    {
        string rsa_base64 = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(stringHex_to_charHex(Rsa_588)), (Rsa_588.length() / 2));

        string format_rsa_base64 = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                                   rsa_base64.substr(0, 64) + "\n" + 
                                   rsa_base64.substr(64, 64) + "\n" +
                                   rsa_base64.substr(128, 64) + "\n" +
                                   rsa_base64.substr(192, 64) + "\n" +
                                   rsa_base64.substr(256, 64) + "\n" +
                                   rsa_base64.substr(320, 64) + "\n" +
                                   rsa_base64.substr(384, 8) + "\n" +
                                   "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

        publicKey = (unsigned char*)format_rsa_base64.c_str();

        return true;
    }
```

All this is to use the RSA_public_encrypt() Api of OpenSSL, The problem is that I'm doing things "by hand" and I'm sure it can be done in a more efficient way but I do not know what. I hope you can guide me on how to do things using OpenSSL functions.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. An RSA key is already either public or private. Possibly you have an RSA key *pair,* in some undisclosed format, in which case you are just going to have to disclose it; or possibly you already have an RSA public key and you want to change it into another format such as one of the PKCS formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types and keysizes of RSA keys. It would be more helpful, if you specify each.

There are 2 steps to achieving what you want.

1. use OpenSSL function **PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey** to load the key into an OpenSSL RSA structure.

   - Paste the hexadecial characters into a text file.
   - Read the text file into a **fp** with "r" option, using fopen.
   - Reading the key using this function automatically puts the public key into the format you want (which is **PEM format**).
2. use **RSA_public_encrypt** to encrypt as you said. Use the RSA structure from above.

---

There are declarations for functions above.

```
 1. RSA *PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(FILE *fp, RSA **x,
                                    pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
 2. int RSA_public_encrypt(int flen, const unsigned char *from,
unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your key is a ASN.1 formated RSA key pair then you want to use the use the [d2i_RSAPrivateKey_xxx](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/d2i_RSAPrivateKey.html) methods to read in the key and use the [PEM_write_bio_RSAPUBLICKey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey.html) method to write out your public key.

e.g.

```
bool load_and_export_rsa_public_key()
{
    auto* bio = BIO_new_file("rsa.key", "rb");
    if(!bio) return false;
    auto const rsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey_bio(bio, nullptr);
    BIO_free(bio);

    if(!rsa) return false;

    auto const bio_out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(bio_out, rsa);
    RSA_free(rsa);
    return true;
}
```

UPDATE:
If it's just a RSA public key then you can use:

> ASN1 RSA format: [d2i_RSAPublicKey_bio](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/d2i_RSAPublicKey_bio.html)
>
> PEM RSA format: [PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey.html)

which will return a RSA pointer you can use.  It all depends on the format you have your RSA public key in.

Comment: It's not a key pair, it's just the public key.